# Cantor space closed

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $A=$ $\{$ $\sum_n a_n3^{-n}$ : $a_n$ $=$ $0,2$ $\}$.

Show that $A$ as a subset of $[0,1]$ is closed:

My idea consists of taking a point $x$ in the complement of $A$.  However, I'm not sure then how to proceed.
Can every element of [0,1] be expressed as a sum of $b_n3^{-n}$?  Where  $b_n=1?$  would the complement of A be of that form?
May I have hints?

Please use this definition of A rather than any alternative definition.

Comment: You can define the Cantor set inductively as an intersection of closed sets, and conclude as closedness is stable under arbitrary intersection

Comment: Reread my edit please @Don Thousand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X=\{0,2\}^\mathbb{N}$ has the product topology, check that $f: X \to [0,1]: f(x)=\sum_n a_n 3^{-n}$ is continuous.

As $X$ is compact, so is its image $A$. And compact subsets of $[0,1]$ are closed.

Comment: is there a way to do it without compactnes?

Comment: @topologicalmagician what’s wrong with compactness?

Comment: haha nothing. I love compactness, its amazing. The professor assumed that this can be done without compactness, and I was wondering how that method would work. Moreover, I'm not sure what you mean by $\{$ $0,2$ $\}$ $^$ $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @topologicalmagician $\{0,2\}^\mathbb{N}$ is the countable product of two point spaces (discrete). Compact by Tychonoff’s theorem.